# I want to inherit SPIFFS class to extend it for my methods. Is it possible?

Tags: c++, arduino, esp32

I have ESP32 project using Arduino framework and I have problem. I want to create my class, which would be inheriting from SPIFFS class. Just want to add readConfig method and use it in my project.

Is it possible?

I am using something like.
SSDReader.h

```
#pragma once
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <SPIFFS.h>
#include <FS.h>

using namespace fs;
class SSDReader: public SPIFFSFS {
  public:
    void getConfig();

};

extern SSDReader ssd;
```

SSDReader.cpp

```
#include "SSDReader.h"

void SSDReader::getConfig() {

}
```

main.cpp

```
#pragma once
#include <Arduino.h>
#include "include/SSDReader.h“

void setup() {
  // Init SSDReader
  if (!ssd.begin()) {

  }
}

void loop() {

}
```

It compiles, but the ssd is then:

```
.pioenvs/esp32dev/src/main.cpp.o:(.literal._Z5setupv+0x10): undefined reference to `ssd'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
*** [.pioenvs/esp32dev/firmware.elf] Error 1
```

Thanks,
Regards,
Petr Sourek

Comment: What do you mean by "unknown"? Like there is no real instance of `ssd` so the linker complains? You should use exact error messages, so we don't have to guess.

Comment: I am sorry for that, I had posted whole code into main topic and the compiler error too.

Comment: So yes, you declare there will be variable of type `SSDReader` named `ssd` but you never created one. Put `SSDReader ssd;` into the `SSDReader.cpp`

Comment: Now I am getting to state I was wrestling yesterday, with the constructor missing.

src/include/SSDReader.cpp:7:11: error: use of deleted function 'SSDReader::SSDReader()'
SSDReader ssd;
^
In file included from src/include/SSDReader.cpp:1:0:
src/include/SSDReader.h:7:7: note: 'SSDReader::SSDReader()' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
class SSDReader: public SPIFFSFS {
^
src/include/SSDReader.h:7:7: error: no matching function for call to 'fs::SPIFFSFS::SPIFFSFS()'

Comment: In file included from src/include/SSDReader.h:3:0,
from src/include/SSDReader.cpp:1:
/Users/djmanas/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/libraries/SPIFFS/src/SPIFFS.h:25:5: note: candidate: fs::SPIFFSFS::SPIFFSFS(fs::FSImplPtr)
SPIFFSFS(FSImplPtr impl);
^
/Users/djmanas/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/libraries/SPIFFS/src/SPIFFS.h:25:5: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided

Comment: /Users/djmanas/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/libraries/SPIFFS/src/SPIFFS.h:22:7: note: candidate: fs::SPIFFSFS::SPIFFSFS(const fs::SPIFFSFS&)
class SPIFFSFS : public FS
/Users/djmanas/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/libraries/SPIFFS/src/SPIFFS.h:22:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided

Comment: If the parent is not default constructible, you can't use default constructors in child class too. I'd recommend to read some tutorial about c++ inheritance

Comment: The parent looks like this.

https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/SPIFFS/src/SPIFFS.h

Can you please provide me what I have to search on google, and learn in order to be able to solve this issue? My googleFu is not strong enough :-(

Comment: Btw, they are using this: `SPIFFSFS SPIFFS = SPIFFSFS(FSImplPtr(new VFSImpl()));` to make an instance

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191451/discussion-between-kiiv-and-petr-sourek).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to KIIV I have been able to edit my code like this.

SSDReader.h

```
#pragma once
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <SPIFFS.h>

using namespace fs;
class SSDReader : public SPIFFSFS {
  public:
    SSDReader() : SPIFFSFS{ SPIFFS } { };
    void getConfig();

  protected:
};
```

SSDReader.cpp

```
#include "SSDReader.h"

//SSDReader::SSDReader() {}


void SSDReader::getConfig() {

}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include "include/SSDReader.h"
//#include "include/Display.h"

// Variables
SSDReader ssd;
bool enableSerial = false;

//Display display;

void setup() {
  if (enableSerial)
    Serial.println(9600);

  // Init SSDReader
  if (!ssd.begin()) {

  }

}

void loop() {

}
```

And it works. Thank you very much. I am going to selfstudy more.